# Compare structs except one field golang

Tags: go, struct

I am comparing two structs and want to ignore a single field while doing so.

```
type test struct {
  name string
  time string
} 

func main() {
  a := test{"testName", time.Now().Format(time.UnixTime)}
  // after some time
  b := test{"testName", time.Now().Format(time.UnixTime)}

  fmt.Println(a.Name == b.Name) \\ returns true Desired outcome
  fmt.Println(reflect.DeepEqual(a,b)) \\ returns false

}
```

`reflect.DeepEqual()` does not allow for us to ignore a field and have manually done the comparison one field at a time.

What is the idiomatic way to go about this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### 1. With embedding

One option would be to group fields that should take part in the comparison into a different struct which you can embed in your original. When doing the comparison, just compare the embedded fields:

```
type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

type Doc struct {
    Person
    Created time.Time
}

func main() {
    d1 := Doc{
        Person:  Person{"Bob", 21},
        Created: time.Now(),
    }
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond)
    d2 := Doc{
        Person:  Person{"Bob", 21},
        Created: time.Now(),
    }

    fmt.Println(d1 == d2)               // false
    fmt.Println(d1.Person == d2.Person) // true
}
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/KNMfSXoj9P).

If the struct does not contain pointers, slices, maps etc., you can simply compare the embedded values using `==`. Otherwise use `reflect.DeepEqual()` to compare them.

### 2. Temporarily modifying the excludable fields

You may also choose to temporarily modify the fields you don't want to compare: *make them equal* so the comparison result will only depend on the rest of the fields:

```
a := test{"testName", time.Now().Format(time.StampMilli)}
time.Sleep(time.Millisecond)
b := test{"testName", time.Now().Format(time.StampMilli)}

// Save and make excluded fields equal:
old := a.time
a.time = b.time

fmt.Println(a.name == b.name)        // true
fmt.Println(reflect.DeepEqual(a, b)) // true

// Restore:
a.time = old
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/3OKJ6gi_Hl).

Another variation is to make a copy of one of the struct values, and modify and compare that to the other, so no need to restore the original, also this is "more concurrent-friendly":

```
// Make copies and make excluded fields equal:
a2 := a
a2.time = b.time

fmt.Println(a2.name == b.name)        // true
fmt.Println(reflect.DeepEqual(a2, b)) // true
```

Try this on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/rIOBVWBOhB).

### 3. Implement your own, custom comparison

If you can't or don't want to go with the above solutions, you can always create your own:

```
func compare(a, b test) bool {
    return a.name == b.name
}


fmt.Println(a.name == b.name) // true
fmt.Println(compare(a, b))    // true
```

Try this on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/LJ4cVhyGui).

**Notes:**

This isn't "friendly" at first, as the custom `compare()` function requires you to check all involved fields, but its implementation may use the above methods, e.g. (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/jRxOQyPXAM)):

```
func compare(a, b test) bool {
    a.time = b.time // We're modifying a copy, so no need to make another copy
    return reflect.DeepEqual(a, b)
}
```

You could also pass pointers to `compare()` to avoid copying the original struct, e.g. (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/4xI4P0VDRu)):

```
fmt.Println(a.name == b.name) // true
fmt.Println(compare(&a, &b))  // true

func compare(a, b *test) bool {
    a2 := new(test)
    *a2 = *a
    a2.time = b.time
    return reflect.DeepEqual(a2, b)
}
```

Comment: How to compare two interfaces except some fields? Because I can't `call of reflect.Value.FieldByName on interface Value`. The original requirement is that I need to compare two json string except some fields, so I unmarshal them to interfaces and compare the interfaces.

Comment: @icza maybe this answer is different with `cmp` package nowadays ?

Answer (score 19):

Idiomatic way would be to implement your own `func (o MyStruct) Equal(o2 MyStruct) bool` method.

Comment: this answer gives specific solution to the problem

Answer (score 6):

For testing purposes, you can use [cmpopts](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp/cmpopts) - this allows (exported) fields to be ignored when `cmp.Equal` from the [cmp](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/go-cmp@v0.5.8#section-readme) package is used.

```
func main() {
    a := test{"testName", time.Now().Local().String()}
    // after some time
    b := test{"testName", time.Now().Local().String()}

    fmt.Printf("a: %#v\nb: %#v\n", a, b)

    if !cmp.Equal(a, b, cmpopts.IgnoreFields(test{}, "Time")) {
        log.Fatalf("mismatching data")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If your fields are exported, you may use `reflect` to check them. E.g.:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Foo struct {
    Name string
    Date int
}

func (f *Foo) EqualExcept(other *Foo, ExceptField string) bool {
    val := reflect.ValueOf(f).Elem()
    otherFields := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(other))

    for i := 0; i < val.NumField(); i++ {
        typeField := val.Type().Field(i)
        if typeField.Name == ExceptField {
            continue
        }

        value := val.Field(i)
        otherValue := otherFields.FieldByName(typeField.Name)

        if value.Interface() != otherValue.Interface() {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

func main() {
    f := &Foo{
        "Drew",
        30,
    }

    f2 := &Foo{
        "Drew",
        50,
    }

    fmt.Println(f.EqualExcept(f2, "Date"))
    fmt.Println(f.EqualExcept(f2, "Name"))

}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/DlhE8aZGwa

Answer (score 0):

Using reflect, we can get the kind and perform a deep check on every kind.

```
    func EqualExcept(expected, actual interface{}, exceptFields ...string) bool {
    valE := reflect.ValueOf(expected)
    valA := reflect.ValueOf(actual)

    switch valE.Kind() {
    case reflect.Array, reflect.Slice:
        {
            for i := 0; i < valE.Len(); i++ {
                e := valE.Index(i).Interface()
                a := valA.Index(i).Interface()
                if !EqualExcept(e, a, exceptFields...) {
                    return false
                }
            }
            return true
        }
    case reflect.Map:
        {
            for i := 0; i < len(valE.MapKeys()); i++ {
                key := valE.MapKeys()[i]
                keyStr := toString(key)
                if stringInSlice(keyStr, exceptFields) {
                    continue
                }

                e := valE.MapIndex(key)
                a := valA.MapIndex(key)

                if !EqualExcept(e.Interface(), a.Interface(), exceptFields...) {
                    return false
                }
            }
            return true
        }
    case reflect.Struct, reflect.Interface:
        {
            for i := 0; i < valE.NumField(); i++ {
                typeField := valE.Type().Field(i)
                if typeField.Tag == "json:\"-\"" || stringInSlice(typeField.Name, exceptFields) {
                    continue
                }

                e := valE.Field(i)
                a := valA.FieldByName(typeField.Name)

                if !EqualExcept(e.Interface(), a.Interface(), exceptFields...) {
                    return false
                }
            }
            return true
        }

    case reflect.Ptr:
        {
            if valE.IsNil() {
                return valA.IsNil()
            }

            e := valE.Elem()
            a := reflect.Indirect(valA)
            return EqualExcept(e.Interface(), a.Interface(), exceptFields...)
        }

    case reflect.String, reflect.Int, reflect.Int64, reflect.Float32, reflect.Float64, reflect.Bool:
        return expected == actual

    default:
        return valE.Interface() == valA.Interface()
    }
}

func toString(v reflect.Value) string {
    bytes, _ := json.Marshal(v.Interface())
    return string(bytes)
}

func stringInSlice(a string, list []string) bool {
    for _, b := range list {
        if b == a {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Here is the demo:

[Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/iE6fnPD0XZ-)